# Получение значения из формы

Tags: python, django

Нужно получить данные из input, чтобы по этому запросу выдать ссылку на необходимую страницу. Проще говоря, поисковик по сайту.

Выдает ошибку
*AttributeError at /wiki/search 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'*

Есть шаблон. Вот его часть. В entries передаю список со всеми имеющимися страницами:

```
{% block form_list %}
  <form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="name" list="pages" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia" autocomplete="off">
      <datalist id="pages">
          {% for page in entries %}
            <option value="{{ page }}"></option>
          {% endfor %}
      </datalist>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('wiki/<slug:page>', views.page, name="page"),
    ...
    path('wiki/search', views.search, name="search"),
]
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    entries = entries_list()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST('name')
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
            "search_page": name, "entries": entries})
def page(request, page):
    entries = entries_list()
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/page.html", {
        "title": page, "content": open_md(page), "entries": entries})
```

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде решил

views.py

```
def search(request):
    entries = entries_list()
    name = request.GET.get("q")
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/page.html", {
        "entries": entries, "title": name, "content": open_md(name)})
```

html:

```
{% block form_list %}
  <form action="/search" role="search">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="q" list="pages" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia" autocomplete="off">
      <datalist id="pages">
          {% for page in entries %}
            <option value="{{ page }}"></option>
          {% endfor %}
      </datalist>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
path('search', views.search),
```